# Tradingview - PineScript - Convert Strategy from v2 to v5 but different outcome

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So I was converting an old pine script v2 via on tradingview to v5 which all worked fine but when I came to use it, it gave me a different result to the v2 script once converted, . Same setting  on input, properties but different result.

---

version=2

```
Based on Heikin Ashi Strategy v2 by breizh29
strategy("Heikin Ashi Strategy [Krypt]", shorttitle="HA Strategy [Krypt]", overlay=true)

res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="60")
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="180")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(30,"Slow EMA Period")
slomas = input(1,"Slow EMA Shift")
logtransform = input(false, "Log Transform")
stoploss = input(true, "Stop Loss")
showplots = input(true, "Show Plots")

ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, logtransform ? log(close[hshift]) : close[hshift])
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, logtransform ? log(close[mhshift]) : close[mhshift])

fma = ema(mha_close[test], fama)
sma = ema(ha_close[slomas], sloma)

plot(showplots ? (logtransform ? exp(fma) : fma) : na, title="MA", color=#0094ff, linewidth=2, style=line)
plot(showplots ? (logtransform ? exp(sma) : sma) : na, title="SMA", color=#ff6a00, linewidth=2, style=line)

golong = crossover(fma, sma)
goshort = crossunder(fma, sma)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=golong, stop=(stoploss ? high+syminfo.mintick : na))
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=goshort, stop=(stoploss ? low-syminfo.mintick : na))`
```

---

version=5

```
Based on Heikin Ashi Strategy v2 by breizh29
strategy("Heikin Ashi Strategy [Krypt] Alert", shorttitle="HA Strategy [Krypt] Alert v5 script", overlay=true)

res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame",defval="60")
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", defval = "180")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(30,"Slow EMA Period")
slomas = input(1,"Slow EMA Shift")
logtransform = input(false, "Log Transform")
stoploss = input(true, "Stop Loss")
showplots = input(true, "Show Plots")

ha_t = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
ha_close = request.security(ha_t, res, logtransform ? (close[hshift]) : close[hshift])
mha_close = request.security(ha_t, res1, logtransform ? (close[mhshift]) : close[mhshift])

fma = ta.ema(mha_close[test], fama)
sma = ta.ema(ha_close[slomas], sloma)

plot(showplots ? (logtransform ? fma : fma) : na, title="MA", color=#0094ff, linewidth=2)
plot(showplots ? (logtransform ? sma : sma) : na, title="SMA", color=#ff6a00, linewidth=2)

golong = ta.crossover(fma, sma)
goshort = ta.crossunder(fma, sma)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=golong, stop=(stoploss ? high+syminfo.mintick : na))
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=goshort, stop=(stoploss ? low-syminfo.mintick : na))
```

[V2 Pine Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xVeP.jpg)
[V5 Pine Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWLd7.jpg)

In my opinion, big different i changed condition

V2

```
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, logtransform ? log(close[hshift]) : close[hshift])
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, logtransform ? log(close[mhshift]) : close[mhshift])
```

V5

```
ha_close = request.security(ha_t, res, logtransform ? (close[hshift]) : close[hshift])
mha_close = request.security(ha_t, res1, logtransform ? (close[mhshift]) : close[mhshift])
```

How to keep condition in v2 convert to v5
And v5 to same result to v2 Pine Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the security function has [changed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed) starting from v3.

If you want to achieve the same results, you should add `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` to your `security()` call.

> ***lookahead:*** It can take on the form of two different values:
> ***barmerge.lookahead_off*** (and this is the default for Pine Script™
> ***version 3***) or ***barmerge.lookahead_on*** (which is the default for Pine
> Script™ ***version 2***).